# Long texts getting cropped in Text components React-Native

Tags: react-native, text

I have a functional component `Comment`, which dynamically receives data to show in a socialmedia like application. If a long text is given as a comment, the height of the card is increased accordinly but the last line is cropped by a half. I tried with many solutions I found in other posts, like `textBreakStrategy={'simple'}` or `flexWrap: 'wrap'` in the container, but nothing is solving this issue.
As additional information, a lot of `Comment`s are being rendered in a container `ScrollView`, and the `ScrollView` is inside a `View` with `flex: 1`. I dont think there's any problem with the container.

To give a better idea, here's a picture of a `Comment` with a long text getting cropped in the last line:

[image]

Here is the component's code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'
import { es } from 'date-fns/esm/locale'

const Comment = props => {

    const amITheCreator = (comment, user) => {
        if (comment && user) {
            return comment.creator_id === user.id;
        }
        return false;
    };

    const user = props.user;
    const comment = props.item;
    const date = new Date(comment.createdAt);
    const relativeDate = formatDistanceToNow(date, { addSuffix: true, locale: es });
    const itsMine = amITheCreator(comment, user);
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(comment.liked);
    const [likes, setLikes] = useState(comment.likes);

    const toggleLike = () => {
        if (liked) {
            setLikes(likes - 1);
        } else {
            setLikes(likes + 1);
        }
        setLiked(!liked);
    };

    const onLike = () => {
        toggleLike();
        props.onLike(comment.id);
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ ...styles.container, backgroundColor: itsMine ? '#0095ff' : 'white' }}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={{ ...styles.owner, color: itsMine ? 'white' : '#222b45' }}>{comment.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ ...styles.date, color: itsMine ? 'white' : '#8f9bb3' }}>{relativeDate}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <Text style={{ ...styles.content, color: itsMine ? 'white' : '#222b45' }}>{comment.content}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <AntDesign name={'heart'} color={itsMine ? 'white' : '#8f9bb3'} size={14} />
                    <Text style={{ ...styles.likes, color: itsMine ? 'white' : '#8f9bb3' }}> {likes ? likes : '0'} Me gusta</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={onLike}>
                    {liked ?
                        <AntDesign name={'heart'} color={'#ff2d55'} size={20} />
                        :
                        <AntDesign name={'hearto'} color={itsMine ? 'white' : '#8f9bb3'} size={20} />
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View >
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        marginBottom: 15,
        borderRadius: 7,
        padding: 10,
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    owner: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    date: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: 'white',
    },
    contentContainer: {
        padding: 5,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    content: {
        fontSize: 16,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 5,
    },
    likes: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});

export default Comment;
```

Comment: I see a few style props that are not necessary for the text component. Like alignSelf, width and padding at content style object. Actually you do not need this for text. Normally the height is dynamic based on the text length and the text is always visible. Can you try to remove the unnecessary style props for Text (comment.content)

Comment: Okay. I already removed the unnecesary styles. It didnt change the cropped text, any other suggestion?